# como hacer tablas en un pdf con Itextsharp

Tags: vb.net

necesito ayuda para poder hacer tablas con Itextsharp pero para visual basic .net ya que los videos y documentación que he visto lo trabajan con C# y no termino de entenderle, si alguien tiene documentación o me podría asesor sería de mucha ayuda, gracias